# Amazon AWS RDS vs EC2 with SQL Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have a web application on Windows Server and SQL Server and want to move it to Amazon AWS.

We will have an EC2 Windows Server running IIS but we have a question about if it better to have an RDS SQL Server database or if we should better have an EC2 bundled with SQL Server.

For performance and replication what do you recommend?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I would always have a separate server infrastructure for database vs. application server, as these will need to scale by different factors. Especially if you want Master-(Read Only) slave on your DB replication, I would definitely go with RDS.  If you need master-master or ability to write on slvae RDS will not meet that criteria.

Answer (score 13):

We recently migrated a SQL database with some deadlock issues to AWS and looked carefully at AWS -- it was not a match for us due to a huge performance risk vis a vis deadlocks, so we went with EC2 instances.  The users have been very happy with the performance.

From a performance perspective, Amazon's provisioned IOPS features are excellent, and these are available on both RDS and on the EC2 server instances. RDS also has killer automated backup capabilities.  It's truly a set up and forget type of system.

AWS RDS [does not support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport) SQL Server replication. If your intent is to replicate something from your site to the AWS instance, then your options are to use a Windows Server base instance with your own SQL Server ISO/license, or to use a pricier EC2 AMI based on SQL Server.  RDS has its own replication system that will support replication to another RDS instance (even on a  different availability zone) to increase resilience or automate failover.  With RDS you could also roll your own site to cloud snapshot replication by using bcp on prem, but that might require you to alter your application or schema.

A couple of advantages we found to using an EC2 instance over RDS:

- With an EC2 instance, you get sysadmin on the database instance and administrator on the underlying Windows Server.   RDS does not allow this, and in fact, with RDS you lose access to the shell and to the underlying Windows Server administration tools.  This means that you cut out some basic tools for performance management: System Monitor, tracerpt.exe, Windows System Resource Manager, etc.
- With an EC2 instance, you can use SQL Server Agent to run jobs that include command line or powershell scripts.  RDS does not allow this.

Comment: SQLServer Agent is available on RDS. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html

Comment: @Khonsort yes it does, and as stated in your link: _"Because SQL Server Agent is running on a managed host in a DB instance, there are some actions that are not supported. Running replication jobs and running command-line scripts by using ActiveX, Windows command shell, or Windows PowerShell are not supported."_

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your IIS is on one EC2 instance and SQL on another EC2 vs RDS...

RDS performance vs EC2 performance vs price seems fluid but there is one major impact for Microsoft SQL Server users and RDS that may help you decide.

You can not use Backup / Restore to move DBs in and out of RDS.

If this matters, EC2 is the only way to go.

Of course, there are a number of options other than Backup / Restore including a decent data migration designed to work with Azure that also works with RDS but it often fails for some complex environments.

Comment: Since july 2016 native backup/restore is supported by SQLServer RDS with some restrictions. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 4):

Answering after experiencing both - 
if all new development -fresh database(no production level data) - no need to think and just go with RDS.

But if working with existing application and database. easiest way is SqlServer Instance on EC2.  this will save you lot of hassle of datatype errors not supported by RDS. 
Moving existing Data to RDS can be a big pain. i learned my lesson by hard way. And end up using ec2 sql server instance.

Comment: Very interesting. Are you using custom datatypes? Do you have a link to content on that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Its clearly best practice to keep the DB and web layer on separate machines, so an EC2 instance for your IIS and RDS for the database would work fine.

You could also use 2 EC2 instances, one for IIS and one for the DB - that will also work.

RDS is probably the best option, if you don't take into account price - without knowing the traffic on your site, how important the DB is (i.e. could you afford to be down for 8 hours? could you afford to lose the last 15 minutes worth of db changes etc), there is no right answer...your budget and your requirements will be the deciding factors...

All that said, I have some low traffic sites that run with IIS and SQL Server express on a single EC2 instance, and they run just fine - and is very affordable and easy way to get on AWS, with the option of  improving that config as your budget allows and traffic dictates.

Comment: Agreed, EC2 definitely gives more control over AWS costs.  There are probably valid use cases where database servers can be shut down at night.  And, it's easy to provide data security using scheduled AMI snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [AWS Architecture Center](http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/). The [Web Application Hosting datasheet](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf) fits your scenario. Deploying each [application layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx#Layers) to a suitable infrastructure service will help you building a reliable and performant application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to definitely go with RDS. Moving existing data to RDS used to be a big pain for us too, before we found the Cloudbasic SQL RDS AlwaysOn tool on the AWS Marketplace:

[https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OU0PE5M/ref=_ptnr_blg_’blg4’](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OU0PE5M/ref=_ptnr_blg_%E2%80%99blg4%E2%80%99)

This tool was designed to continuously geo-replicate RDS from one region to another for HA/DR and reporting. But it can also be used for moving data in and out of RDS.  The best part is, it supports DB instance replication for SQL Server Web Edition. You can even replicate from SQL Standard to Web edition, from SQL 2008 to 2014 etc.

Another reason RDS is recommended over EC2 with SQL Server is the Multi-AZ HA feature. However note that it works for the pricey Standard and Enterprise editions only, and the replica is not accessible (it is for mySQL and oracle, but is not for SQL Server). It cannot be used for reporting. You just know it is there but cannot actually access it. And Multi-AZ works within the AWS region only. If you are fine with the cost and the limitations, it is definitely recommended. Alternatively you can use the Cloudbasic tool to continuously replicate RDS SQL Web edition from i.e. your primary AWS Virginia RDS to RDS in Oregon for reporting and DR. And it costs a lot less compared to RDS Multi-AZ with SQL Standard.